# How to add items from text file to lists

Tags: python

I'm complitely new to Python. I have a text file where I have a datetime and a number like this:

`01.01.2000 00:00;300`.

I want to add date and the number in a list, but I've no idea how to do that. I know how to split lines into columns and here's a piece of my code.

```
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if (len(line) == 0):
        break
    line = line[:-1]
    column = line.split(';')
    dates = column[0].split(' ')
    date =  dates[0].split('.')
    time = column[1].split(':')
```

Comment: Welcome future pythonista! Have a look at the datetime library and the functions strptime and strftime. They should get you far!

Comment: If you're using python2: `import dateparser` and `dateparser.parse(<stringGoesHere>)` can help quite a bit.

Comment: what's the part you're having issues with exactly ? turning the "date" part into a `datetime.date` object ? adding the value('s) to a list ?

Comment: I'm using Python3. I'm having issues turning the date part into a datetime.date/datetime.datetime object. Either my code says that something is out of range or syntax error. I've tried to use strptime also but haven't been lucky with that...

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify those points, and add the exact error messages __and tracebacks__ (as well as an example of the data that raised the error), cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: To use strptime you'll need the correct format string: this one:`%d.%m.%Y %H:%M` should to the trick. (assuming the date time format of your strings is always: dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to make a datetime from plain text. Here is the code:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(year, month, day,hour,minute)
```

And after that you can simply add it to the list.

```
l.append(x)
```

you can easily specific what exactly you want to add

```
l.append(x.hour)
```